# How to update datagridview at same time of datainsetion in db

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two winforms

Namely ADDLaundry and Laundry details

laundry details have btn onclick event which raise addlaundry form and we can add laundry details ...i need to see the details add in addlaundry form in laudndry details grid with out closing the form. any body have any idea....

i used this code :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           IsDone= objLaundry.InsertLaundry(txtItems,txtRate);
            if(IsDone==true)
            {
                objLaundry.ClearFields(txtItems,txtRate);

                //PolosysHMS.Masters.frmLaundry obj = new frmLaundry();
                //obj.dgvLaundry.DataSource = null;
                //obj.LoadGrid();
                //obj.Show();
            }
```

but this create addition object and i want to close existing laundry details and again open new constructor....??

Comment: Detail grid is in existing page? If yes so just add bind grid functionality after the save functionality.

Comment: but save functionality is in another page...

Comment: Do you have save functionality page open with opendialogbox ? If yes so below the opendialogbox codes just add bind grid functionality.

Comment: it's ok in web forms but in winforms we cannot do like this....i used to did in modalpopup in webforms but in winforms we cannot access datagridview of another forms because it s private function and if we change it to static it affects on some other parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create Function in Winforms which is having grid for refreshing grid..

Now when you Click Button for opening ADDLaundry form..Do like this:

```
 FormADDlaundry frm = new FormADDlaundry();
 Frm.ViewGrid += new FormADDlaundry.doevent(BindGrid);
 Frm.show();
```

Now On AddLaundry Form

```
 public delegate void doEvent();
 public event doEvent ViewGrid;
```

and Now when you add Laundry by click button. Call also ViewGrid event.
Your Work Done!!

Comment: i paste the code in Addbtn click event the first code  and on winform which add laundarydetails the second code but still not working...

Comment: code on second winform :laundary_Items    public partial class frmLaundry_Items : Form
    {
        PolosysHMS.Classes.Laundry objLaundry = new Classes.Laundry();
        public bool IsDone = false;
        public bool IsEdit = false;

        public delegate void doEvent();
        public event doEvent ViewGrid;

Comment: code on winform1 laundary :
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            frmLaundry_Items obj = new frmLaundry_Items();
            // isedit false to activate save functions. 
            obj.IsEdit = false;
            //obj.Show();
            //update the grid after insertion in grid. 
            obj.ViewGrid += new frmLaundry_Items.doEvent(LoadGrid);
            obj.Show();
            //dgvLaundry.DataSource = null;
            //LoadGrid();
        }

Comment: I've attached Link check From that..https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B893d39kVeIvcGhjUG80ZG05OWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hardik in my office google drive is restricted i will check from my room and respond....thank for your kind help

Comment: Do you get SourceCode from Google Drive??

Comment: is it usefull to your project??

Comment: ya very much useful but in my page its not working.....i will try once again with eg